# Как оставить открытым под меню при переходе на другую страницу

Tags: jquery

Вот песочница http://jsbin.com/duvudako/1/
При переходе на файл index2.php под меню скрывается.

```
<ul id="menu-name" class="menu">
        <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="index2.php">Первый уровень есть вложение</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Второй уровень без вложения 1</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Второй уровень без вложения 2</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Второй уровень без вложения 3</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Второй уровень без вложения 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.widget .menu-item:has(.sub-menu)').children('a').toggle( // Выбираем все ссылки из .menu-item имеющего во вложении .sub-menu

    function() {
        jQuery(this).parent('.menu-item').children('.sub-menu').css('display', 'block'); // Показываем вложенный пункт 
        document.location.href=$(this).attr('href');
    }, function() {
        jQuery(this).parent('.menu-item').children('.sub-menu').css('display', 'none'); // Скрываем вложенный пункт
    });
});

.menu .menu-item {
    margin: 5px; /* Отступы для всех list-item */
}
.menu .sub-menu {
    display: none; /* Скрываем вложенные пункты */
    margin-left: 10px; /* Отступ слева для вложенных list-item */
}
```

Comment: а что вы хотите, если вы переходите на совершенно другую страницу?

Comment: Чтобы открылось подменю

Comment: вопрос был риторическим, если вы не обратили внимание. Иными словами: если вы совершаете переход по ссылке, то страница полностью обновится, и текущее содержимое заменится на новое. поэтому не стоит ожидать, что содержимое старой страницы по-прежнему будет радовать вас своим присутствием

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте флаг, который бы показывал факт того что меню нужно отображать.

```
<a href="index2.php?menu=visible">Первый уровень есть вложение</a>
```

А далее проверяйте внутри index2.php этот флаг

```
if($_GET['menu'] == 'visible') { /* а тут добавьте на страницу кусок JS который развернет ваше меню */ }
```